# Delete other data with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

I am making a application for my internship. We play games in the break, and I am making a application to keep track of the score.

I can add games with players. After that, I can edit the game and assign a winner.
The games table & winners table are both seperate.

```
Players: ID(PK), name
Games: ID(PK), player_1(FK), player_2(FK) --- Connected to players.id
Winners: ID(FK), name (FK) --- winners.id connected to games.id, name to players.
```

If I haven't assigned a winner in the game, I can safily delete a record. However, if I assigned a winner, I can't: *Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails*

I know why, because the winner is connected with a game. But how can I remove a game and immediatly delete the winner from the other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete the foreign key constraint from `winners`:

```
ALTER TABLE winners DROP FOREIGN KEY yourforeignkeyname
```

Then recreate it with [ON DELETE CASCADE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

```
ALTER TABLE winners 
ADD CONSTRAINT yourforeignkeyname 
FOREIGN KEY (ID) 
REFERENCES games(ID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Now when you delete a game, the winner rows will also be deleted.

Comment: Worked for one table. The other 2 tables I am getting an error: (Errcode: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

Comment: What other tables? This code affects the `winners` table.

Comment: I know. I have 3 tables, I simplified the things I said. I have fifa_winners, darts_winners & billiard_winners. Connected with fifa_games, dart_games & billiard_games. It only worked for the darts but not for the other ones.

Comment: You must do the same for all of them, but give **different** names to each constraint when you recreate them.